# CSS two double div, one fixed one shifts horizontal

Tags: html, css

The problem is that one div shifts down and one up, why?
I did two double divs, both inline-block and floated to right, the same inside each block.
I'm tried many changings, without any solution.

```css
.lawyer-online {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 200px;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 10px;
}
.lawyer-avatar {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 float:right;
}
.lawyer-avatar-relative {
 position: relative;
}
.lawyer-name-box{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0em;
 right: 0em;
 width: 100%;
 height: 2em;
    background: rgba(25, 126, 215, 0.9);
 color: #fff;
}
.lawyer-name-box span{
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}
.lawyer_description {
 background: rgba(25, 126, 215, 0.5);
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 display: inline-block;
 clear: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="lawyer-1" class="lawyer-online">
 <div class="lawyer-avatar">
  <div class="lawyer-avatar-relative">
   <img src="http://wdd.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/angry-judge-100x100.jpg">
   <div class="lawyer-name-box">
    <span>name name</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="lawyer_description">short text</div>
</div>
<div id="lawyer-2" class="lawyer-online">
 <div class="lawyer-avatar">
  <div class="lawyer-avatar-relative">
   <img src="http://wdd.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/angry-judge-100x100.jpg">
   <div class="lawyer-name-box">
    <span>name name</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="lawyer_description">long text long text long text</div>
</div>
```

[image]

The problem is that one div shifts down and one up, why?
I did two double divs, both inline-block and floated to right, the same inside each block.
I'm tried many changings, without any solution.

Comment: You can't float an element and use `inline-block` at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is occurring because an `inline-block` receives by default `vertical-align: baseline`, which doesn't always align elements in a desired manner.

You can rectify this by explicitly specifying `vertical-align: top` in your declaration block for `.lawyer-online`. (Or middle/bottom, they work too as values.)

```css
.lawyer-online {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 200px;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 10px;
 vertical-align: top;
}
.lawyer-avatar {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 float:right;
}
.lawyer-avatar-relative {
 position: relative;
}
.lawyer-name-box{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0em;
 right: 0em;
 width: 100%;
 height: 2em;
    background: rgba(25, 126, 215, 0.9);
 color: #fff;
}
.lawyer-name-box span{
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}
.lawyer_description {
 background: rgba(25, 126, 215, 0.5);
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 display: inline-block;
 clear: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="lawyer-1" class="lawyer-online">
 <div class="lawyer-avatar">
  <div class="lawyer-avatar-relative">
   <img src="http://wdd.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/angry-judge-100x100.jpg">
   <div class="lawyer-name-box">
    <span>name name</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="lawyer_description">short text</div>
</div>
<div id="lawyer-2" class="lawyer-online">
 <div class="lawyer-avatar">
  <div class="lawyer-avatar-relative">
   <img src="http://wdd.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/angry-judge-100x100.jpg">
   <div class="lawyer-name-box">
    <span>name name</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="lawyer_description">long text long text long text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should add a `vertical-align: top` on your `.lawyer-online` class.

```
.lawyer-online {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `vertical-align:top`

```
.lawyer-online {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```